# RStudio won't run any code after quitting session

Tags: r

I have been working on a code in RStudio. When I ran the following line

`read.table("file", sep = "\t", fill = T, header = F)`

it got stuck and i tried to quit R but i only got the "Quitting R Session" message and nothing happened. I had to force quitting the app from activity monitor. Now every time I restart RStudio it won't run any code and if I try to close the app, again I can't and I have to force quit. I have tried
terminating R from the "Session" tab in RStudio and then closing again the app, restarting my mac and uninstalling and reinstalling RStudio but nothing works.

Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: Try to look into your `home` folder and see if there is any .RData there? Remove them may help.

Comment: You may check [here](https://osxuninstaller.com/uninstall-guides/uninstall-r/) for uninstalling R completely before installing.  I suspect some files got corrupted.  Once you completely remove all the folders, try reinstalling

Comment: you can uncheck the option to "restore .rdata into workspace at startup" in your global options. not sure if it still is, but it used to be the default